# Can I pass a vector as an initial_sum and a different function to std::accumulate?

Tags: c++

I have the code below. Our exercise is using [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) algorithms.

Is there is a way to use std::accumulate for this code?

If you have a different STL algorithm for this code it is also fine! (We will also test on our time complexity.)

```
void multiplyAndAddVector(const int num, std::vector<double>& tomultiply, std::vector<double>& toadd)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tomultiply.size(); i++)
    {
        toadd[i] += (tomultiply[i] * num);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what `std::accumulate` does. I don't know of any C++ algorithm that implements this, very specialized, algorithm.

Comment: STL? Isn't it the standard C++ library?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, the STL (standard template library) is now known as the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is not an appropriate algorithm here, since it only gives you a single value as a result.

You need to read 2 ranges, and modify one, for which you can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) like this:

```
std::transform(toMultiply.begin(), toMultuply.end(), // input range 1
               toAdd.begin(),                        // input range 2
               toAdd.begin(),                        // output range 
               [num](double mul, double add) { return add + mul * num; });
```